Unable to perform long audio synthesis. Neither the client project number: 863017906842 nor ID: project-219819 matches the resource project: bucket
I am trying to generate long audio from text with the Google text-to-speech api, using the google/cloud-text-to-speech PHP client.
I have created the Service Account and given it the permissions in the bucket, as explained in all two links
https://angnasution.com/2023/07/long-audio-api-for-google-cloud-text-to-speech/
https://angnasution.com/2023/07/using-google-cloud-text-to-speech-api-with-python/
The PHP code I use is as follows:
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\Name\Projects\google-text-to-speech\project-219819-da3fdd6a76ad.json');

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\Client\TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SsmlVoiceGender;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesizeLongAudioRequest;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

try {

    $client = new TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesizeClient();

    $synthesisInputText = (new SynthesisInput())
        ->setText('Hola, ¿cómo estás? gracias por venir.');

    $voice = (new VoiceSelectionParams())
        ->setLanguageCode('es-ES')
        ->setName('es-ES-Standard-A')
        ->setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender::FEMALE);    
        
    $effectsProfileId = 'handset-class-device';    
    
    $audioConfig = (new AudioConfig())
        ->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::LINEAR16)
        ->setSpeakingRate(0.75)
        ->setEffectsProfileId(array($effectsProfileId));

    $request = (new SynthesizeLongAudioRequest())
        ->setParent('projects/project/locations/global')
        ->setOutputGcsUri('gs://bucket/audios/ejemplo.mp3')
        ->setInput($synthesisInputText)
        ->setVoice($voice)
        ->setAudioConfig($audioConfig);
    $response = $client->synthesizeLongAudio($request);
    $audioContent = $response->getAudioContent();                   

    file_put_contents('output-long.mp3', $audioContent);
    echo '<audio src="output.mp3" controls />' . PHP_EOL;
    
    $textToSpeechClient->close();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

But when I run it I get the following error

{ "message": "Unable to perform long audio synthesis. Neither the client project number: 863009906802 nor ID: project-219819 matches the resource project: bucket", "code": 3, "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [] }

Any ideas?

On Stack Overflow, don't answer your question within your own post.  Post an answer just like anyone else, and accept it as correct so it's perfectly clear to future readers what the solution is.  I've edited the question to remove the answer, now please post your answer correctly.

As per the error, you need to use the project ID, see the BOLD part below:
$request = (new SynthesizeLongAudioRequest()) -\>setParent('projects/PROJECT ID/locations/global') -\>setOutputGcsUri('gs://bucket/audios/ejemplo.mp3') -\>setInput($synthesisInputText) -\>setVoice($voice) -\>setAudioConfig($audioConfig);
